# Usar filter_input(FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) em um array com itens do tipo inteiro

Tags: php, filtro, lógica, sanitize

Tenho o seguinte form:

```
<form action="<?=PATH_ROOT?>professor/cadastrar" method="post">
     Matrícula:
     <input type="text" name="matricula">

     <br><br>
     Nome:
     <input type="text" name="nome">

     <br><br>
     Turmas:<br>
     <select name="turmas[]" multiple="multiple">
          <?=$this->optionsTurma?>
     </select>

     <br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
</form>
```

Onde o **select turmas[]** terá um tamanho dinâmico, ou seja, pode ter 1, 2, 3, 4, ... , pois é uma tabela do banco.

E estou modificando a validação usando **`filter_input();`** ficando assim:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && !empty($_POST)) {

     $post['matricula'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'matricula', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
     $post['nome'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
     $post['turmas'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'turmas', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

     if ($this->model->save($post))
          echo '<script>alert("Cadastrado com sucesso!");</script>';
     else
          echo '<script>alert("Erro ao cadastrar.");</script>';
}
```

Meu **`$post['turmas']`** sempre retornará item(ns) do tipo inteiro. O problema é que sempre retorna `boolean false` creio que pelo motivo de estar dando o `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` em um array.

```
$post['turmas'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'turmas', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Como posso dar um `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` para cada item do meu array de turmas trazido do form, é possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY` como o quarto argumento da função `filter_input`.

```
$post['turmas'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'turmas', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
```